# How to select rows based on 3 IF statements?

Tags: r, filter, dataset, filtering

I have a dataset of patients. In this dataset I have 4 columns ID, PatientID, PhaseCode, EXAMDATE and EXCHANGE.

```
ID  |  PatientID  |  PhaseCode  |  EXAMDATE  |  EXCHANGE
--------------------------------------------------------
1   |  7366       |  ADNI1      | 21/08/2015 |     1
2   |  7366       |  ADNIGO     | 21/08/2015 |     3
3   |  7366       |  ADNI2      | 21/08/2015 |     2
4   |  7363       |  ADNI1      | 21/08/2015 |     1
5   |  7363       |  ADNI1      | 21/08/2015 |     1
6   |  7366       |  ADNI1      | 21/08/2015 |     4
7   |  7366       |  ADNIGO     | 21/08/2015 |     5
8   |  7366       |  ADNIGO     | 21/08/2015 |     0
9   |  7366       |  ADNI2      | 21/08/2015 |     1
```

There are 3 types of Phases (ADNI1,ADNIGO,ADNI2) in which data was recorded. As you might have noticed that a patient my have the same phase name repeated more than once or maybe only have record for one phase.

I need help with selecting patients that have records all of the phases. For example if the patient don't have record for ADNI2 then I would like to remove it. The condition is something like: If patient 7366 has record where phasecode is equal to ADNI1, ADNIGO and ADNI2 then include in the dataset.

Please kindly help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a little `tidyr` and `dplyr`. First we `complete` all combinations of PhaseCode/PatientID, then we `group_by` PatientID, then we remove those Patients which have any NA from the completion:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
dat %>% complete(PhaseCode, PatientID) %>%
        group_by(PatientID) %>%
        filter(!any(is.na(ID)))
```

Comment: I kept getting this error: "Error in function_list[[i]](value) : could not find function "complete"

Comment: do you have a recent version of tidyr installed? Try running `install.packages("tidyr")`

Comment: Yes, but for some reason wasn't working. I tried it on a different machine and it worked :) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
subset(d, as.character(PatientID) %in% 
  names(which(tapply(PhaseCode, PatientID, function(x) length(unique(x)))==3)))
```